# Forcing JBoss AS 7 to use static files from source (development) directory in Spring project

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, static-files

I want to speed up development cycle: *read/write code, build, deploy, test* by eliminating **build** and **deploy** stage for such file types:

- CSS (.css)
- JavaScript (.js)
- images (.png, .jpg, .gif)

as CSS/JS/img are **static** files (does not require **build** stage) and I hope that JBoss can scan for file timestamp changes to update static file cache.

I have such code in **web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/**</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/css/**</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/images/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So I need change it to something that also give full path to CSS/JS/imgs, like `~/devel/$proj/src/main/webapp`. Also I think that static content may be served by JBoss itself instead of Spring.

As summary: how to configure Java EE project with JBoss AS 7 to serve static files from selected (in my case development) directory, while other files deployed as usual through .war file (I deploy by `mvn -DskipTests=true package jboss-as:deploy`)?

Answer (score 1):

After spending 4 hours I make it work! But not in general case because solution based on new Spring 3.x series.

For general case solution you must implement own servlet, like this done n famous blog article: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html

I don't like to write code but like to configure already prebuild components!

So first I change request handler for all URL to `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Before I have:

```
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
```

so `*.js`, `*.css`, `*.png` files managed by default container (JBoss) servlet and any options further have no effect...

Next I use Spring 3.0 features `<mvc:resources>` (`xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`) and `file:` resource type:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="file:/home/user/devel/proj/src/main/webapp/css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:/home/user/devel/proj/src/main/webapp/images/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="file:/home/user/devel/proj/src/main/webapp/js/"/>
```

Any time I save `.js` or `.css` file and refresh web-page in browser I get new content!

*So reduce static content deploy time from 2 minute to 1 second*!!!

**UPDATE** After switching to Tomcat 7 I configure context `/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/conf/Catalina/localhost/CTXNAME.xml`:

```
<Context docBase="/home/user/devel/proj-dev/src/main/webapp"
         reloadable="true">
    <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext"
               extraResourcePaths="/WEB-INF/classes=/home/user/devel/proj-dev/target/classes,/WEB-INF/lib=/home/user/devel/proj-dev/target/proj/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
            virtualClasspath="/home/user/devel/proj-dev/target/classes;/home/user/devel/proj-dev/target/proj/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true"/>
</Context>
```

according to:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/resources.html
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html

Now JS/CSS/JSP files update by `F5` in browser. In order to use new `.class` invoke `mvn compile`. To bootstrap invoke `mvn package`