# I want to use development version of JSP files in Spring project. Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

In previous question [Forcing JBoss AS 7 to use static files from source (development) directory in Spring project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409465/forsing-jboss-as-7-to-use-static-files-from-source-development-directory-in-sp) I ask for JS/CSS files and after 4 hours of docs reading and experimenting resolve problem myself.

But I don't familiar with Spring/Servlet internals to force Spring to **use JSP file from local files system path (development files)**. I try:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="file:/home/user/devel/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
</bean>
```

but when I access application page I get error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /app/file:/home/user/devel/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
```

which I think somehow come from [ServletContext.getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)...

My goal is to make edit-deploy-test cycle shorter.

Please don't suggest *JRebel* or *DCEVM* or other solution. Just direct answer...

Comment: Shouldn't that be `file:///`?

Comment: I tried and have same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After switching to Tomcat 7 (from Jboss AS 7) I configure context `/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/conf/Catalina/localhost/CTXNAME.xml`:

```
<Context docBase="/home/user/devel/proj-dev/src/main/webapp"
         reloadable="true">
    <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext"
               extraResourcePaths="/WEB-INF/classes=/home/user/devel/proj-dev/target/classes,/WEB-INF/lib=/home/user/devel/proj-dev/target/proj/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
            virtualClasspath="/home/user/devel/proj-dev/target/classes;/home/user/devel/proj-dev/target/proj/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true"/>
</Context>
```

according to:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/resources.html
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html

Now JS/CSS/JSP files update by `F5` in browser. In order to use new `.class` invoke `mvn compile`.

To bootstrap invoke `mvn package`. Context name come from `.xml` file name.

Answer (score -1):

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
              <property name="prefix"> 
                    <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
              </property>
              <property name="suffix">
                 <value>.jsp</value>
              </property>
</bean>
```

in prefix you have to give only relative path start with /WEB-INF/

Comment: I know. And this is shame because I deploy **war**-file to JBoss so it uses **.jsp**-files from archive but I want that it uses from local file system from development hierarchy.