# Is it possible to tell maven-compiler-plugin to delete .class file when I remove/rename corresponding .java file?

Tags: java, spring, maven, ant, inversion-of-control

I read official docs `mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-compiler-plugin -Ddetail`:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

and didn't find option which imply automatic deletion of `.class` files for no longer lived `.java` files.

Also I didn't find such option for Ant:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

It is annoying to clean project and then build again after class renaming or moving it to another package...

If I don't do this IoC framework detect duplicate matches for beans binding.

**UPDTE** I it is not possible with maven-compiler-plugin is there any plug-in which detect alone `.class` files and delete them?

I want to get *consistent build* each time I run `mvn package` and preserve incremental nature of build (so avoid `mvn clean`).

Comment: I'm not aware of any such option, nor am I sure it would be desirable.

Comment: Main argument for such option is **consistent/non-broken build**

Comment: Right, I understand the desire. But class files could conceivably come from other sources than main compilation tasks, so you'd need to explicitly track the source tree. Seems like that would be a fairly trivial plugin; maybe that'll be my afternoon project.

Comment: See [this thread](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-dev/201209.mbox/%3C1346957577.46441.YahooMailNeo@web28906.mail.ir2.yahoo.com%3E) for some recent discussion of adding this to Maven.

Comment: @Joe Very interesting thread! +1

Answer (score 4):

If you're following the Maven conventions and your code is under `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` then you will respectively have it compiled to `target/classes` and `target/test-classes`. With that said, the `maven-clean-plugin` removes everything from your `target` directory.

Consider the following:

```
mvn clean package
```

This will remove all your compiled classes and rebuild them.

Clearly, when you do refactorings which involve you moving/renaming classes, you will need to do a clean compilation in order to be certain you don't have any left-overs.

The compiler plugin is not meant to deal with anything else other than compilation. Maven's plugins are strictly separated into self-contained units of functionality.

Comment: With `mvn clean` I loose incremental build... Huge time cost. +1

Comment: You seriously must understand that Maven itself cannot know what code you've changed in your IDE during your refactoring. It's not creeping behind your back just to look over your shoulder and check if you're doing things it doesn't expect you to. It just expects you to conform to it's way of doing things. :)

Comment: I have very simple project without source file preprocessing. So expect to get benefits from this!

Answer (score 2):

According to me there is no other solution than doing maven-clean. Otherwise the .class files won't get removed. 
If you are using Eclipse or STS then you can configure your tomcat to auto publish the project after each changes in resources.

That may help you.

Comment: Yea, good point to resources! They also must be removed after renames/deletion! +1

Comment: I use another technique for resources (I prefer **Emacs** to **Eclipse** for `.js`/`.jsp`/`.tag` files): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477790/i-want-to-use-development-version-of-jsp-files-in-spring-project-is-it-possible